# Postfix server on AWS EC2 not receiving emails

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ec2, postfix-mta

I have set up a postfix and dovecot server in AWS EC2 by following the below article:

https://linoxide.com/ubuntu-how-to/setup-postfix-dovecot-mysql-ubuntu-1604/

I have configured my Outlook to send and receive emails through this server.

I am able send emails to gmail or yahoo but I am not able to receive from them.No bounce messages nor erros in /var/log/mail.log.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

(Should be a comment, but reputation and all that)

Do you have an MX record pointing to your server? That's my current best guess because the article you linked doesn't mention MX Records. That would be the record that lets everyone know where to forward emails to your domain.

Comment: Yes I have set the MX record pointing my domain name to the server EIP.

Comment: @Name_me Do you have a security group that allows incoming TCP Port 25? Access Control List that doesn't block inbound/outbound TCP Port 25? It sounds like Gmail/Yahoo can't reach your server. How long ago did you set up the MX Record? It could be a TTL issue too.